# Filling a 2D array without a for loop in C

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to fill a 10X10 int array with the number 46 and want to do it in one line, with out the use of a nested forloop. I've been trying to use memset but a doubt I'm using it for the right purpose. Can I do this in one line?

Kind Regards,
David

Comment: 1. Which programming language is in question? Is it C?
2. Which type of array you are talking about? Int?

Comment: Good question! It's in c, I'll edit my post aha

Comment: And yes it's an int array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say it is an `int` array then you cannot use memset, as if you do:

```
memset (my_ptr, 46, 10*10);
```

Then you will be writing the value `46` in the `100` first **bytes** of your array, and if each `int` occupies `4 bytes` then you are just assigning a weird value to the `25` first `ints`.

If you are in `C` then a single `for` loop is enough, no need to nest.